# Problem with Java GridLayout and adding Buttons

Tags: java, swing, panel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I want to add 100 buttons into an `GridLayout` and my code works but sometimes it only adds one button and if I click where the other buttons belong the button where I clicked appears. 
it happens totally randomly and I don't get it.
Here is my code:

```
    public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    GameUI controler;
    GridLayout gameLayout = new GridLayout(10,10);
    JButton gameButtons[] = new JButton[100];
    ImageIcon ice;
    JButton startButton;
    JButton exitButton;
    ImageIcon startIcon;
    ImageIcon exitIcon;
    URL urlIcon;
    private int i;

    public GamePanel(GameUI controler) {
        this.setLayout(gameLayout);
        this.controler = controler;
        urlIcon = this.getClass().getResource("/icons/Overlay.png");
        ice = new ImageIcon(urlIcon);
        makeButtons();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    }

    public void makeButtons() {
        for(i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
            gameButtons[i] = new JButton(ice);
            this.add(gameButtons[i]);
            revalidate();   
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

update:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.net.URL;


public class GameUI extends JFrame {

ImageIcon i;
Image jFrameBackground;
JButton startButton;
JButton exitButton;
ImageIcon startIcon; 
ImageIcon exitIcon;


public GameUI() {
    setResizable(false);
    this.setSize(1200, 800);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(null);








    BackGroundPanel backGroundPanel = new BackGroundPanel();
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel(this);
    ButtonPanel buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();

    panel.setSize(500,500);
    panel.setLocation(100, 150);
    backGroundPanel.setSize(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
    backGroundPanel.setLocation(0,0);
    buttonPanel.setSize(390,50);
    buttonPanel.setLocation(100,100);
    this.add(backGroundPanel);
    this.add(panel);
    this.add(buttonPanel);




    backGroundPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);



}





public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {







    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(
                new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {



                        GameUI ui = new GameUI();
                        ui.setVisible(true);


                    }


                }

            );




}
```

}

Comment: Your posted code does not include a [mcve], code that we can compile, run and test, including a main method, and so I'm forced to guess. *Perhaps* you've got painting code elsewhere that does not appropriately call a super's painting method. *Perhaps* you don't call `pack()` on your top-level window (often a JFrame) after adding all components and calling `setVisible(true)` on it. Side note that you will want to call `revalidate()` after the for loop, not within it although this will not fix your problem.

Comment: Side note 2: you almost never will want to override the JPanel's `paint(...)` method, and instead would want to override `paintComponent(...)` although this won't matter much here, since your paint method is doing nothing.

Comment: Side note 3: You will not want to have your GUI classes implement your listener interfaces as that gives the class too much responsibility -- please read the "[single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)". I've removed the `implements...` declaration from your posted code, since it is not relevant to your problem, but feel compelled to pass on what I feel is important advice for your future code. Again, please consider improving this question and your posted code so that it is in fact answerable without our having to resort to guessing.

Comment: so i added where i create the jpanel , i hope that will help you. anyways the game panel class isn't a gui class the buttons should be game elements of "sinking ships". if i add the buttons in the paint method it won't work neither with the paintComponent. i tried to add pack() but it won't work it just shrinks my jframe to the minimum.

Comment: 1) Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible 2) The revalidate() and repaint() is not needed, since the panel hasn't been added to the frame. You only need to invoke those methods when AFTER you add components to a visible GUI. But in your case the code is executed from the constructor so they are not needed.

Comment: This `this.setLayout(null);` is not good at all. Get rid of it and instead use the layout managers appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you're using a null layout, and this is the source of your problems.

You're using the null layout to try to layer JPanels, one on top of the other, and that is not how it should be used or what it is for, nor how you should create backgrounds. This is having the effect of the background covering your buttons until your mouse hovers over them.

Instead if you wish to create a background image, I would recommend that you:

- create a JPanel, say called BackgroundPanel,
- override its paintComponent method,
- call its `super.paintComponent(g);` on your method's first line
- then draw the image it should display
- then **give it a decent layout manager**
- and **add your GUI components to it**
- Make sure that any JPanels added to it are made transparent via `.setOpaque(false)`

Other options include using a JLayeredPane, but you really don't need this just to have a background.

For example, the following code produces:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameUI2 {

    private static final String IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/"
            + "Butterfly_Nebula_in_narrow_band_Sulfur%2C_Hydrogen_and_Oxygen_Stephan_Hamel.jpg";
    private static final String BTN_IMG_PATH = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Crystal_Project_Games_kids.png";

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        BufferedImage bgImg = null;
        BufferedImage btnImg = null;
        try {
            URL bgImgUrl = new URL(IMG_PATH);
            URL btnImgUrl = new URL(BTN_IMG_PATH);
            bgImg = ImageIO.read(bgImgUrl);
            btnImg = ImageIO.read(btnImgUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        BackgroundPanel2 mainPanel = new BackgroundPanel2(bgImg);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GamePanel2 gamePanel = new GamePanel2(btnImg); 
        mainPanel.add(gamePanel);        

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BackgroundPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private Image backgroundImg;

    public BackgroundPanel2(Image backgroundImg) {
        this.backgroundImg = backgroundImg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (backgroundImg != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet() || backgroundImg == null) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            int w = backgroundImg.getWidth(this);
            int h = backgroundImg.getHeight(this);
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GamePanel2 extends JPanel {
    public static final int MAX_BUTTONS = 100;
    private static final int IMG_WIDTH = 40;
    JButton[] gameButtons = new JButton[MAX_BUTTONS];

    public GamePanel2(Image buttonImg) {
        setOpaque(false);
        if (buttonImg.getWidth(this) > IMG_WIDTH) {
            buttonImg = buttonImg.getScaledInstance(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_WIDTH, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        }
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(buttonImg);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < gameButtons.length; i++) {
            int finalIndex = i;
            JButton btn = new JButton(icon);
            btn.addActionListener(e -> {
                String text = String.format("Button: %02d", finalIndex);
                System.out.println(text);
            });
            add(btn);
            gameButtons[i] = btn;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The background image doesnt cover the buttons on the grid if i delete it the buttons are still hidden

Comment: @paulschmitz82: Still posit that your null layout is at fault. get rid of it, use layouts proper, and see what happens.

Comment: thank you very much , it works now, but how can i remove the gaps between the buttons?

Comment: and is it possible to change the size of the gridlayout?